# Vue JS - Get Auth headers on redirection back from the Auth server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, http-headers

I have a VueJS UI running on port 80, and a Node backend on 82. Node JS is used for Auth and proxying APIs that require certain headers. The flow is as follows:

1. UI makes an API call to Node
2. Node checks for Authn status and redirects to the Authn server
3. Authn server redirects back to the UI

The redirect in the 3rd step sends some headers and user info which I am trying to access, because I need to display it in the UI. Is it possible to access these headers?

Comment: You can access the headers inside `response.headers` at the UI end.

Comment: Auth is not handled by Axios, so there is no response object!

Comment: I guess then you need to add some code in the question so people can help you with the exact thing instead of guessing the answer.